# Unwrapping Labels and converting toInt()

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am trying to do this tutorial here. I am a total beginner, this would be my first iOS app period:

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/calculator-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift

Here is my code:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isTypingNumber = false
    var firstNumber = 0
    var secondNumber = 0
    var operation = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var calculatorDisplay: UILabel!

    @IBAction func numberTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        var number = sender.currentTitle

        if isTypingNumber {
            calculatorDisplay.text = calculatorDisplay.text! + number!!
        } else {
            calculatorDisplay.text = number

            isTypingNumber = true
        }
    }


    @IBAction func calculationTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        isTypingNumber = false

        firstNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt()!

        operation = sender.currentTitle!!
    }

    @IBAction func equalsTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        isTypingNumber = false
        var result = 0

        secondNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt()!!

        if operation == "+" {
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber
        } else if operation == "-" {
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber
        }

        calculatorDisplay.text = "\(result)"

    }
}
```

Here is what's happening. I get an error saying Value of Optional type Int? not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ?

It offers to fix it by adding an exclamation point, then says that's wrong, and offers to delete the exclamation point. See screenshots:

[image: First error]
[image: Second error]

I mostly understand the concept of optionals and how to use them, but this is baffling to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is confusing.  The issue is that `calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt()!` is using *optional chaining* due to the `?` after `text`.  The result of an *optional chain* is always an optional value, even if you unwrap the last item in the chain by adding `!`.

The `!` at the end of:

```
calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt()!
```

only unwraps the `Int?` that is returned by `toInt()`.  Why does `toInt()` return an optional `Int`?  Because the string may not be convertible to an `Int` so `toInt()` returns `nil` in those cases.  For example, `"two".toInt()` would return `nil`.

To unwrap the result, you can use parentheses to group the entire optional chain so that `!` will unwrap the whole chain:

```
secondNumber = (calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt())!
```

or remove the *optional chaining* by *force unwrapping* `text` with `!`:

```
secondNumber = calculatorDisplay.text!.toInt()!
```

But these will crash if `text` is `nil` or if the string couldn't be converted to an `Int`.  The better way to do this is to use *optional binding*:

```
if let secondNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt() {
    // when we get here, we know `text` wasn't nil and we
    // know it converted to an Int.  At this point secondNumber
    // is safely unwrapped and ready to use.  Its type is Int.
}
```

---

Another option is to use the *nil coalescing operator* `??`.  If you want to use a default value when `text` is `nil` or if the text doesn't convert successfully to an `Int`, then you can do something like this:

```
let secondNumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt() ?? 0
```

This will safely unwrap the optional created by `toInt()` if `text` is not `nil` and the conversion succeeded.  Otherwise, `0` will be assigned to `secondNumber`.  In either case, `secondNumber` is of type `Int`.

Comment: While it's true the person asking the question is using optional chaining, it really has no relevance to why toInt() returns an optional Int. Calling toInt() on a String instance is not guaranteed to return a value, such as if the person wrote "thirty".toInt(), vs "30".toInt(). Please consider refining your answer to stay on point, because your other suggestions are spot on and perfect. I would personally suggest using optional binding, because nil coalescing returning a 0 may be a valid value, and could throw off their logic.

Comment: No, but the fact that `toInt()` returns an optional or not doesn't explain why `calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt()!` is still an optional.  That is what is causing him trouble.  The `!` at the end unwraps only the result of `toInt()`, but the chain still returns an optional because of the `?` after text.  That is my point.

Comment: Ack! You're right, I misread it thinking the whole expression was being unwrapped vs just the toInt(). Sorry about that. Tested and confirmed too.

Answer (score 2):

The function `toInt()` of `String` returns `Int?`. This means that it is not guaranteed to have a value. When you use `!` on the response of this function, you are basically saying "nah, don't worry, bro; it's got a value fo'rell".

A more appropriate usage (as described by the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH7-SW26)):

```
if let secondnumber = calculatorDisplay.text?.toInt() {
  // do your processing.
}
```